# UICollectionview - prefetchItemsAt indexPaths - not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to use prefetching which was introduced in iOS 10. But unable to achieve it.

I do set the delegate and enable the prefetching. But when i set a breakpoint or console log at prefetch, it does not pass through the function ever.

I know on fast scroll, the prefetching is skipped. but even on slowest scroll, its never been called

```
var dataSource = [IndexPath: Any]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        mainCollectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = true
        mainCollectionView.prefetchDataSource = self
    }

    //Other stuffs
}

//This is not being called
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    print("Prefectch")
    for indexPath in indexPaths {
        dataSource[indexPath] = fetchDataSource(indexPath)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.dataSource = dataSource[indexPath] ?? fetchDataSource(indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the "UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching" delegate in your vc?

Comment: "prefetchItemsAt indexPaths" function in the above, is the UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching delegate

Comment: Did you implement 

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching

Comment: Yes, i did. If not, "mainCollectionView.prefetchDataSource = self" would throw an error!

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   self.collectionView(collectionView, prefetchItemsAt: [indexPath])
}
```

To trigger the prefetch, and remove:

```
collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
```

If you have it.
This was by me the case.